# Why yacc have memory leak at exit?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, bison, yacc, lex

when I execute my lex/yacc program with valgrind, it find memory leak. But I would know if it's possible to delete this memory leak. The output of valgrind is:

```
==10006== 
==10006== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10006==     in use at exit: 16,458 bytes in 3 blocks
==10006==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 10 frees, 16,684 bytes allocated
==10006== 
==10006== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==10006==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10006==    by 0x4028FA: yyalloc (lex.yy.c:1852)
==10006==    by 0x402411: yyensure_buffer_stack (lex.yy.c:1552)
==10006==    by 0x400DA9: yylex (lex.yy.c:686)
==10006==    by 0x40312D: yyparse (parser.tab.c:1183)
==10006==    by 0x40462F: parse (Parser.c:10)
==10006==    by 0x4045EB: main (main.c:21)
==10006== 
==10006== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==10006==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10006==    by 0x4028FA: yyalloc (lex.yy.c:1852)
==10006==    by 0x401FA5: yy_create_buffer (lex.yy.c:1387)
==10006==    by 0x400DD3: yylex (lex.yy.c:688)
==10006==    by 0x40312D: yyparse (parser.tab.c:1183)
==10006==    by 0x40462F: parse (Parser.c:10)
==10006==    by 0x4045EB: main (main.c:21)
==10006== 
==10006== 16,386 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 3
==10006==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10006==    by 0x4028FA: yyalloc (lex.yy.c:1852)
==10006==    by 0x401FDC: yy_create_buffer (lex.yy.c:1396)
==10006==    by 0x400DD3: yylex (lex.yy.c:688)
==10006==    by 0x40312D: yyparse (parser.tab.c:1183)
==10006==    by 0x40462F: parse (Parser.c:10)
==10006==    by 0x4045EB: main (main.c:21)
==10006== 
==10006== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10006==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10006==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10006==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10006==    still reachable: 16,458 bytes in 3 blocks
==10006==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10006== 
==10006== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10006== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

And my lex:

```
Chiffre [0-9]
Lettre [a-zA-Z]
Alphanum ({Chiffre}{Lettre})+

%{

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

%}
%%
-[a-zA-Z]+ {
yylval.
string = strdup(yytext);
    return OPTION;
}

[a-zA-Z0-9_\-./]+ {
    yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
    return WORD;
}
"||" {
return OR;
}
"|" {
return PIPE;
}
"&&" {
return AND;
}
"&" {
    return AMPERSAND;
}
";" {
return SEMICOLON;
}
"2>" {
return
ERR_GREAT;
}

">&" {
return
GREAT_AMP;
}

"2>>" {
return
ERR_GREAT_GREAT;
}
">>&" {
return
GREAT_GREAT_AMP;
}
">>" {
return
GREAT_GREAT;
}

">" {
return
GREAT;
}

"<" {
return
LESS;
}

[ \t]+ {
}

"\n" {
return 0;
}

%%
```

And my yacc file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "executor/CmdArg.h"
#include "executor/Command.h"
#include "print.h"
int yyerror(const char *msg) {
    return fprintf(stderr, "YACC: %s\n", msg);
}
%}

%union {
    int number;
    char *string;
};
%token<string> WORD
%token<string> OPTION
%destructor {
free($$);
} <string>
%token<void> SEMICOLON
%token OR AND PIPE AMPERSAND GREAT GREAT_GREAT LESS ERR_GREAT ERR_GREAT_GREAT GREAT_AMP GREAT_GREAT_AMP
%error-verbose
%%

pipeline: cmd_args
background SEMICOLON
pipeline{
end_cmd(SEQUENCING_SEQUENCING);
}
|
cmd_args background
PIPE pipeline{
        end_cmd(SEQUENCING_PIPE);
}
|
cmd_args background
OR pipeline{
        end_cmd(SEQUENCING_OR);
}
|
cmd_args background
AND pipeline{
        end_cmd(SEQUENCING_AND);
}
|
cmd_args background{
        end_cmd(SEQUENCING_NOTHING);
}
|;
cmd_args: WORD list_args params io_list{
        printdebug("YACC COMMMAND : %s\n", $1);
    add_arg($1);
};

list_args: OPTION list_args{
printdebug ("yacc list arg plusieurs: %s\n", $1);
add_arg($1);
}|OPTION{
printdebug ("yacc list arg seul : %s\n", $1);
add_arg($1);
}|;

params: WORD params{
printdebug ("yacc param plusieurs : %s\n", $1);
    add_arg($1);
}
|WORD {
printdebug ("yacc param seul: %s\n", $1);
    add_arg($1);
}|;
background: AMPERSAND{
        set_background();
}
|;

io_list: GREAT WORD{
    set_io(GREAT,$2);
}|GREAT_GREAT WORD{
    set_io(GREAT_GREAT,$2);
} LESS WORD{
    set_io(LESS,$2);
}| ERR_GREAT WORD{
    set_io(ERR_GREAT,$2);
}| ERR_GREAT_GREAT WORD{
    set_io(ERR_GREAT_GREAT,$2);
}| GREAT_AMP WORD{
    set_io(GREAT_AMP,$2);
}| GREAT_GREAT_AMP WORD{
    set_io(GREAT_GREAT_AMP,$2);
}|;


%%

struct CmdArg *temp;
void set_io(enum yytokentype tokentype, char* file){

}
void set_background() {
    temp->_background = 1;
}
void add_arg(char* s){
    if (!temp)temp = new_cmdArg();
    cmdarg_add_argument(temp,s);
    free(s);
}
void end_cmd(Sequencing seq){
    temp->_seq=seq;
    command_add_cmdArg(temp, seq);
    free_cmdArg(temp);
    temp = NULL;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: actually that's bison (not yacc), since it uses bison-specific directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ==10006== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==10006== definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==10006== indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==10006== possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==10006== still reachable: 16,458 bytes in 3 blocks
>
> ==10006== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

Not freeing still reachable memory is quite normal for most programs. Since there is still a pointer to it at exit, it's not really a leak.

Comment: I found yylex_destroy to finish the program with 0 leak.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Oneill comment, the generated lex code provide global functions you can declare (with extern) and call to handle situations like this.  In your specific case, you are looking for the function `int yylex_destroy ( void );`.  When you call that function in your code, it will clear up any remaining memory allocated by the lexer.

Here are the list of functions:

```
int yylex_destroy ( void );
int yyget_debug ( void );
void yyset_debug ( int debug_flag  );
YY_EXTRA_TYPE yyget_extra ( void );
void yyset_extra ( YY_EXTRA_TYPE user_defined  );
FILE *yyget_in ( void );
void yyset_in  ( FILE * _in_str  );
FILE *yyget_out ( void );
void yyset_out  ( FILE * _out_str  );
int yyget_leng ( void );
char *yyget_text ( void );
int yyget_lineno ( void );
void yyset_lineno ( int _line_number  );
```